# Replace text label in Layout view by new text label from CSV table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, pyqgis-3

Currently, I'm stuck working on my first python plugin and hope to get some advice here. The plugin should take a csv file (or .xlsx would be even better) which has two string columns. Column 1 has terms like "Project Name" or "Project Manager" and the second column has the actual names of the project and the manager. The terms of the first column already exist as text labels in the layout view of my QGIS Project. Thus, the plugin should take the table and replace the text labels in the layout view with the actual names in column 2. I hope the purpose of the plugin is clear.

I used the "plugin builder" tool to get the basics and successfully prepared the gui. After that, it gets complicated

That's my code so far:

```
def select_table(self):
    """the name of the input table will be shown in the GUI"""
    filename = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.dlg, "Select input Table",
                                           "", '*.csv, *.xlsx, * .xls, * .ods'))
    self.dlg.table_path.setText(filename)

    """This is supposed to add the table as a layer in QGIS"""
    uri = filename
    table = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "table", "ogr")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(table)

def getTable(self):
    """gets table from the QGIS Project"""
    layer = None
    tablename = self.dlg.table_path.currentText()
    for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers.values():
        if lyr.name() == tablename:
            layer = lyr
            break
    return layer

def setVariable(self):
    """adds the table to a variable"""
    self.inTable = self.getTable()

def change_label(self):
    """gets the fields of the csv file"""
    fields = self.inTable.fields() 
    
    """checks if the label texts are equal to those in the first column
    of the csv file. After replaces the label text with the value
    of the second column of the same object"""
    
    for text in QgsLayoutItemLabel.currentText():
        if text.name() == fields.value.firstCollum()
            text.name() = fields.value.secondCollum
```

I modified several tutorials to come so far but I guess there are some issues in every function I wrote. However, especially tricky is the "change_label" function. It would be great if someone has some advice on that.

Comment: How far into your code does your plugin work successfully? Do you just have issues getting the values from the second column?

Comment: Hey Joseph, thanks for the reply :). The whole code is to big and I didnt really understood what I was wirting there... For now I'm working on the "select_table" function and I'm trying to upload the csv file with its content to my qgis project. It uploads a table but without any content. So now I'm trying to figure out how to add a csv file with the attribute table.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#id1) to see how to add a csv file as a delimited text layer.